# Detect presence of http link or URL in incoming SMS and then delete the same programatically in android

Tags: android, sms

I need to Detect presence of http link or URL in incoming SMS and then delete the same programatically in android.

I need some head start on this one. Any help ?

Comment: post some example, how your message looks like. Have you tried something? Post code also.

Answer (score 0):

## Detect

Matthew (on SO) had  written up a blog post for a great solution for recognising URLs in most used formats such as:

- www.google.com
- http://www.google.com
- mailto:somebody@google.com
- somebody@google.com
- www.url-with-querystring.com/?url=has-querystring

The regular expression used is:

```
/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/
```

However, I would recommend you go to http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/13174566389/url-regular-expression-for-links-with-or-without-the to see the working example.

## Delete

Stop incoming message, get the message text, process it with the above regex and then simulate an incoming message with the modified text.